# How to add bulk number of white spaces in C# code?

Tags: c#

i have a count to add white spaces to the text file. 
For Example:
12 as count means need to add 12 spaces in the existing text file.
is there any possible way?

Comment: Yes there is a way.

Comment: Show us what you've tried already

Comment: @doctor, probably more than one

Comment: Yes, There are some ways.

Comment: Are you trying to pad some values with blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Init a string containing 12 whitespaces.
var str = new string(' ', 12);

// Append string to file
File.AppendAllText("myfile.txt", str);
```

Comment: we also have a option to add space with some content by the use of Padright or left

Answer (score 1):

Yo ucan use the [`string` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a character and a number of times to repeat that character:

```
string twelveSpaces = new string(' ', 12);
```

Then just write the string to your file.

Comment: Definitely prefer this for readability